flutter_local_notification iOS : Duplicate plugin key: FilePickerPlugin
I am adding the flutter_local_notification to my app and I am having this problem on iOS where when the app starts it crashes when trying to call the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback from the app delegat's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
this is my app delegate: 

import UIKit
import Firebase
import Flutter
import flutter_local_notifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
          GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
        }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

I have tried to find if anyone had the same problem, I have seen some loosely related problems but nothing that fixes the problem. This normally should work as stated in the flutter_local_notifications documentation on pub.dev.

flutter_local_notification seems to be using file_picker and my project was already using an older version. updating my pubspec.yaml to use the current version (file_picker: ^8.0.0+1) fixed the problem.
